# Returning a promise to the caller

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a function `HelloWorld` where no promises is returned to the caller. I wonder if it is possible to have this function to adjust to return a promise.

For example:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    // Do something here
    return;
}
```

And in another function of my application I would like to do:

```
...
return HelloWorld()
        .then( ... do something else here ... );
```

How to proceed to have this function return a promise?

Comment: Are you sure you need a promise? Deferreds/Promises are only necessary when working with asynchronous processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function HelloWorld() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  // demo
  setTimeout(deferred.resolve, 1000);

  // this is what you return:
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `HelloWorld` :

```
   var dfr = $.Deferred();
  //some work with it
  return dfr.promise();
```